# Python Script to find file name and size of all files in a directory and save them to a text file for excel import

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

I am pretty new to python and I am trying to:

- Within a user defined directory (1000 images)
- Find the file name (Finished)
- Find the file size (Finished)
- Store to an array
- Store array to text file

`from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
from array import *
import os

Tk().withdraw()
fileDir = askdirectory()
print(fileDir)
dirList=os.listdir(fileDir)
for fname in dirList:
    print fname
    print os.path.getsize(fileDir+"/"+fname)`

Comment: This really has nothing at all to do with tkinter. You use it to display a dialog but everything else is 100% Python.

Answer (score 0):

For storing the file names and sizes in tuples and writing them to a text file you can do something like this:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
from array import *
import os

Tk().withdraw()
fileDir = askdirectory()
print(fileDir)
dirList = os.listdir(fileDir)
data = ((fname, str(os.path.getsize(fileDir + "/" + fname)))  for fname in dirList)

outputFile = open('myoutputfile.csv', 'w')
for entry in data:
    outputFile.write(','.join(entry) + '\n')

outputFile.close()
```

Running this on my python install directory gives a file that looks like this:

```
DLLs,4096
Doc,0
include,32768
Lib,65536
libs,4096
LICENSE.txt,40080
NEWS.txt,285115
python.exe,27136
pythonw.exe,27648
README.txt,54967
Scripts,0
tcl,4096
Tools,4096
```

Which you should be able to open as a .csv file in Excel no problems. Note you may have to quote the file names if any of them have commas, new lines, etc. in them.

For more heavy duty stuff there is the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) but I think it is overkill for such a simple file. In case you are interested using it would look something like this:

```
import csv
with open('myoutputfile.csv', 'wb') as outputFile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(outputFile, dialect='excel')
    for entry in data:
        csvwriter.writerow(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv, os

OUT = 'files_and_sizes.csv'
DIR = '<some directory>'

def main():
    writer = csv.writer(open(OUT, 'w'))
    for f in os.listdir(DIR):
        if os.path.isfile(DIR+ '/' + f):
            writer.writerow([f, os.path.getsize(DIR + '/' + f)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

CSV and Excel play nice with each other, so you shouldn't have any trouble importing it.

Answer (score 0):

some notes about the below implementation:

- generally always use the [csv library](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) because it properly handles special csv characters like commas and quotes. It can be really messy if you will do this escaping by hand.
- it's better not to hard code path delimiter like /, the above two answers won't work on windows machines. By using [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) your code will run correctly on all platforms.

code:

```
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
from glob import glob
from os import listdir
from os.path import join, getsize
import csv

CSV_FILE = 'listing.csv'

path = askdirectory()
files = listdir(path)
rows = [(i, getsize(join(path, i))) for i in files]
with open(CSV_FILE, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: "Above two answers"? The answers aren't guaranteed to appear in any particular order. As I write this there is only one answer above this abswer. Can you make your answer a little less position-dependent?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import os
from Tkinter import Tk
from os.path import join, getsize
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory

# get directory path
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
dirpath = askdirectory()
root.destroy()

# save filename, file size entries for the directory in csv format
entries = ((fn, getsize(join(dirpath, fn))) for fn in os.listdir(dirpath))
with open('entries.csv', 'wb') as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerows(entries)
```